# Not able to connect to add data to correct database in Mongoose. Document gets added to test database

Tags: mongoose

These are my exports to manage database functions - eg. to connect to `mongodb` using `mongoose`.

Note that I haven't specified which database to connect to.

```
module.exports = {

  dbclass: {
      db : null,
      dbClient: null,
      dbConnection:null,

      getDb: function() {
          return this.db;
      },

      getDbClient: function() {
        return this.dbClient;
      },
      
      getDbConnection: function() {
        return this.dbConnection;
      },

      dbConnectCloseMongoose: async function(){
        mongoose.disconnect();
        this.dbConnection=null;
      },

      dbConnectMongoose: async function (){

          console.log(`trying to connect to uri ${process.env.DATABASE_URL}`); //DATABASE_URL=mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017
          const connection = await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
          console.log(`connected to Mongo.`);
          var localdbClient = connection.connections[0].client;
          var localdb;
          console.log(`got MongoClient: `); 
          try {
            localdb = localdbClient.db(process.env.DATABASE);
            console.log(`connected to database ${localdb.databaseName}`); //output - connected to database Questions 
            const collections = await localdb.collections();
            collections.forEach(c => {console.log(`got collection ${c.collectionName}`)}) //output - got collection areas
          } catch(exception) {
            console.log(`something bad happened in dbconnect: ${exception}`);
          } finally {
            this.db  = localdb;
            this.dbClient  = localdbClient;
            this.dbConnection = connection;
            console.log(`db Class db is ${this.db}`);
            console.log(`db Class dbClient is ${this.dbClient}`);
            console.log(`db Class dbConnection is ${this.dbConnection}`);
            }
        }
      }
};
```

Schema is

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: String,
    hints: [String],
    topic: String
}); 


module.exports = questionSchema;
```

I have created a function to add a `document` to `Question` database

```
async function addQuestion (description,hints,topic) {
  var q = null;
  dotenv.config();
  console.log(`adding question:`);
  console.log(`description: ${description}`);
  console.log(`hints: ${hints}`);
  console.log(`topic: ${topic}`);
  var dbClient = mongoUtils.dbclass.getDbClient();
  console.log(`will use db ${process.env.DATABASE}`); //output - will use db Questions 
  var localdb = dbClient.db(process.env.DATABASE);
  console.log(`database is ${localdb.databaseName}`); //output - database is Questions
  
  const Question = mongoose.model(topic, questionSchema,topic);
  
  q = Question({
      description: description,
      hints: hints,
      topic: topic
  });
  await q.save()
  .then ((result) => {
    console.log(`added question ${result}`);
    return result;
  })
  .catch ( (err)=>{
    console.log(`error in adding question: ${err}`);
    return null;
  });
}
```

I am calling this function from a test case. However, the document gets added in `test` database, `areas` `collection` instead of `Questions` database. Why?